# downloading .rar through c#

Tags: c#, file, download, zip

the problem I'm having is that the program i'm making won't download the .zip file from the website

```
try
{

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.horzaneia.beastnode.net/BukkitServer.rar", 
                           @"C:\test");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: in what way won't it? Is there an error? Does the remote file exist?

Comment: The second parameter is a file, not a directory.  Does c:\test already exist?  This is when the actual exception you get would be useful to the question.

Comment: try:     webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.horzaneia.beastnode.net/BukkitServer.rar",  
                           @"C:\test\BukkitServer.rar");

Comment: What does the message box say? Don't keep important error messages to yourself. I suspect you don't have write permission to the root directory of the disk.

Comment: I'm *just now* learning about the `WebClient` class? *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine. Perhaps you should just put c:\test.rar in order to be able to opent it. What e.Message says for you?